# I am trying to find sum of diagonal from 2d array. But getting its address instead of its value .Can anyone explain this to me?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, sum

I was trying to sum the diagonal value in 2d array but getting different Output  ( Total:4194438 ) can any one help me through this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
    int i,j,a,sum,total;
    
    int diagonal_arr[3][3];
    
     for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a);
            diagonal_arr[i][j]=a;
    
        }
     }
    
     for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    
            if(i==j){
               sum= printf("%d\n",diagonal_arr[i][j]);
                total+=sum;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
    printf("Total= %d ",total);
    
    }
```

**OUPUT:**

```
Total= 4194438
```

Comment: That doesn't compile in C# because things like `#include <stdio.h>` aren't valid syntax for the C# language and because `main` isn't `static`. Why have you tagged this as C#?

Comment: `sum= printf(..)`. Read the [printf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). It doesn't return what you seem to think it does.

Comment: `total+=sum;` That's also wrong because `total` is uninitialised.

Comment: @kaylum its initialised  int i,j,a,sum,total;

Comment: @kshitizghimire no it's _declared_, but not initialized. An uninitialized local variable contains an indetermined value.

Comment: @kaylum I see, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
...
total = 0;    // initialize total to 0

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){    
        if (i == j){
           printf("%d\n", diagonal_arr[i][j]);   // you can remove this line
           total += diagonal_arr[i][j];         // add diagonal value
        }
    }
}
...
```